# Threads that have MySQL Connector code in C++ don't end

Tags: mysql, connector

In an XMLRPC server that I'm working on (based off xmlrpc-c) the threads may want to make a MySQL connection to retrieve some data, using the following function:

```
Distribution getEntitySetFromMysql( int id ) {

    Distribution result;

    try {
        sql::Driver *driver = get_driver_instance();
        sql::Connection *con = driver->connect( (std::string)DBHOST, (std::string)USER, (std::string)PASSWORD);
        con->setSchema( (std::string)DATABASE );

        sql::Statement *stmt = con->createStatement();
        std::stringstream query;
        query << "SELECT concept_id, weight FROM entity_set_lines WHERE entity_set_id = " << id;
        sql::ResultSet *res = stmt->executeQuery ( query.str() );

        while (res->next()) {
            result[ res->getInt("concept_id") ] = res->getDouble("weight");
        }

        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        con->close();
        delete con;

    } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        std::cout << " (" << __func__<< ") on line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << e.what();
        std::cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        std::cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << ")" << std::endl;

        if (e.getErrorCode() == 1047) {
            std::cout << "\nYour server does not seem to support Prepared Statements at all. ";
            std::cout << "Perhaps MYSQL < 4.1?" << std::endl;
        }

    } catch (std::runtime_error &e) {

        std::cout << "ERROR: runtime_error in " << __FILE__;
        std::cout << " (" << __func__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;

    }

    return result;
}
```

All works fine, but after a thread runs this code and successfully returns its result, the thread remains hanging and does not exit. What is wrong with this approach? How fundamentaly wrong is this? Is the MySQL connector thread safe?

Comment: This is just a function, what does the thread that call this function do ?

Comment: Only when I call this function from within a thread, it doesn't exit, the rest of the thread's code seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Googling around for a solutions, I came across mentions of `sql::Driver::threadInit()` and `sql::Driver::threadEnd()`. However, as I was on version 1.0.5 of the C++ Connector, these functions were not available to me. Adding a `driver->threadInit();` after getting a driver instance and `driver->threadEnd();` at the end of my function, this problem was resolved.

The following is the mention of this thread init and end functionality in [MySQL's 1.1.0 change history](https://wikis.oracle.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27394600):

> Added Driver::threadInit() and Driver::threadEnd() methods. Every
>   thread of a threaded client must call Driver::threadInit() at the very
>   start of the thread before it does anything else with Connector/C++
>   and every thread must call Driver::threadEnd() when it finishes. You
>   can find an example demonstrating the use in examples/pthreads.cpp. It
>   is strongly discouraged to share connections between threads. It is
>   theoretically possible, if you set certain (undocumented) mutexes, but
>   it is not supported at all. Use one connection per thread. Do not have
>   two threads using the same connection at the same time. Please check
>   the C API notes on threading on the MySQL manual. Connector/C++ wraps
>   the C API. (Lawrin, Andrey, Ulf)

TL;DR: If you come across this problem, make sure that your version of the C++ MySQL Connector is >= 1.1.0 and use the `sql::Driver::threadInit()` and `sql::Driver::threadEnd()` methods to surround your connection code.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

1. libmysql isn't fully [thread safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-threaded-clients.html).
2. the way your code is structured you will leak memory if an exception occurs. you might be better served by either declaring your variables outside the **try/catch** and using a **finally** (or local equivalent) to ensure proper cleanup or using **smart pointers** (if available).

Since you don't show any of the calling or surrounding code it's hard to tell what's actually going on. Do you check the exit code of the thread when it's supposedly done? Can you attach it in a debugger to see what it's doing instead of closing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have found the problem in that I wasn't using sql::Driver::threadInit() or sql::Driver::threadEnd() and wasn't up2date with the latest version of the connector. I will check on your other comments wrt possible leaks as well.

Comment: If this is C++ as it seems it is, "finally" does not exist in this language. You are right, this code has a serious flaw which leaks RAM if exception happens.
Define con, stmt and res outside try block with nullptr values. After try block delete them in reverse order if they are not nullptr: if(res!=nullptr) delete res;....

Answer (score 0):

Actually :

DO NOT USE : `sql::Driver::threadInit()` nor `sql::Driver::threadEnd()`

BECAUSE : you are already using `try()`

YOU FORGOT :

```
res->close();
stmt->close();
con->close();

delete res;
delete stmt;
delete con;
```

EXAMPLE :

```
int connection_and_query_func()
{
     /*connection and query variables*/
     sql::Driver *driver;
     sql::Connection *con;
     sql::Statement *stmt;
     sql::ResultSet *res;
     int err_exception_getErrorCode=0;

     /*results variables*/
     int my_int_from_column_1 = 0;
     double my_double_from_column_2 = 0;
     ....
     std:string my_string_from_column_p = "";

 try
    {
        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("address_name", "user_name", "password");

        /* Connect to the MySQL database */
        con->setSchema("schema_name");

        /* Execute MySQL Query*/
        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("your query statement here");

        /* Read MySQL Query results per column*/
        my_int_from_column_1 = res->getInt(1);
        my_double_from_column_2 = res->getDouble(2);
        ....
        my_string_from_column_p = res->getString(p);

        /* Close MySQL Connection*/
        res->close();
        stmt->close();
        con->close();

        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;
    };

 /* Get last error*/
 catch (sql::SQLException &exception)
    {
        err_exception_getErrorCode = exception.getErrorCode();
    };

 return(0);
};
```

CONCLUSION : this can be executed as many times as you want. The function example (connection_and_query_func()) will close MySQL connection properly after it is done - without adding up processes to your MySQL server!!!

FURTHERMORE : read the official manual https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-cpp-en/connector-cpp-en.pdf

ALTERNATIVE : if you cannot close properly your connection and query from your program/function side (thus adding up processes to your MySQL server) consider the 2 following options:

1/ set all MySQL timeout parameters to 10 sec. or less (for instance);
2/ write a script that SHOW PROCESSLIST and delete processes that are in SLEEP for too long.

Cheers.

Comment: This is not needed: 

res->close();
stmt->close();
con->close();

Destructors of these objects will do this for you.

Comment: Indeed you do not need close(). But why delete the con ? What if you want to maintain the connection opened ?